# Why does FindBugs raise a critical warning when explicitly throwing a NPE?

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, static-analysis, findbugs

Consider the following from [FindBugs error desriptions](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_GUARANTEED_DEREF)

> **NP: Null value is guaranteed to be dereferenced (NP_GUARANTEED_DEREF)**
>
> There is a statement or branch that if executed guarantees that a
>   value is null at this point, and that value that is guaranteed to be
>   dereferenced (except on forward paths involving runtime exceptions).
>
> Note that a check such as if (x == null) throw new
>   NullPointerException(); is treated as a dereference of x.

What is meant by *except on forward paths involving run time exceptions* ?

Also why a check like `if (x == null) throw new
NullPointerException();` raise an warning?

Comment: Instead throw InvalidArgumentException

Comment: Maybe: except if another runtime exception is thrown before the path is executed?

Comment: Isn't it saying that `x` is guaranteed to be `null` at the point of the comparison, so the comparison is redundant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this horribly contrived code:

```
String value = null;
if (5 > 8) {
    value = "foo";
}
doSomething();
if (value.equals("foo")) {
    System.out.println("value is foo");
}
```

Static analysis can prove that `value` will be `null` when `equals` is called, causing a `NullPointerException` to be thrown. However, if the call to `doSomething()` results in a thrown runtime exception, the call to `equals` will never be reached. This is the meaning of "except on forward paths involving runtime exceptions."

As for your second question, FindBugs issues a warning for this code

```
if (value == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

because the effect is the same as what happens when you dereference a `null` value. Since the dereference merits a warning, so does any code which mimics that dereference.

Comment: "because it is identical to what the JVM does "  do we see this warning when we compile?

Comment: @Greek - No, I meant that the JVM throws a `NullPointerException`. I clarified the last paragraph.

Comment: How can checking whether a reference is null be called derefencing? I am not doing something like `value.someAttribute`

Comment: @Greek - Post your actual code. I cannot reason about it without seeing it. I am saying that FindBugs sees the test for `null` with a thrown NPE and treats it as a dereference. It's a rule that has been coded into it; I'm just explaining what it means.

Comment: the code is the same as your second snippet. I see what you are saying. I will accept your answer and +1 for the follow up.